# AMP - Change rel="canonical" from functions.php

Tags: functions, actions

the source action in

> /amp/includes/amp-post-template-actions.php
>   is:

```
add_action( 'amp_post_template_head', 'amp_post_template_add_canonical' );
function amp_post_template_add_canonical( $amp_template ) {
?>

<link rel="canonical" href="<?php echo esc_url( $amp_template->get( 'canonical_url' ) ); ?>" />

<?php
}
```

How I can edit rel from functions.php without editing main file? thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general you can deregister the action's callback, after it's been registered and then register your own before it's invoked with `do_action( '...' )`.

Here's an example:

```
// Add your own with later priority, e.g. 11 or wrap it in another later hook:
add_action( 'amp_post_template_head', 'wpse_amp_post_template_add_canonical', 11 ); 

function wpse_amp_post_template_add_canonical( $amp_template ) 
{
    // Remove the unwanted callback:
    remove_action( 'amp_post_template_head', 'amp_post_template_add_canonical' );

    // Modify this new output to your needs:
    printf( 
        '<link rel="canonical" href="%s" />', 
         esc_url( $amp_template->get( 'canonical_url' ) )
    );

}
```

Comment: Thank you, there is a missed **)** after `get( 'canonical_url' )`